# Ms Access: Running an update query

Tags: ms-access

I got a query which takes out some fields from a table.
How do I use the same query to create a sum of the values of those fields and update the sum to a single field in another table?

Comment: What do you mean by 'takes out some fields'? Are you deleting records? Can't delete records and update records in same action. And what you describe is poor database design.

Comment: I meant to select some values from a datasheet through a query. i got to make the sum of those in that query but how do I update the sum to another datasheet to a field?

Comment: The real question is 'why?' Normally, saving aggregate data is a bad idea. Aggregate data should be calculated when needed. Regardless, you need a query that does the aggregate calc. Why do the extra step of saving it to a table?

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, the only way I can see to accomplish without VBA uses DSum() domain aggregate function.

`UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = DSum("some field", "some table", "some filter criteria here")`

Trying to do this with a nested aggregate query in place of the DSum() returns error 'must be an updatable query'.

Really should re-think your db design.